# How do I calculate a column with a initial value in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) like below:

```
Date      rtns
10/1/2000  NaN
11/1/2000  0.015
12/1/2000  -0.007
```

I want to add a column "accumulated values" starting with 100.0000 on 10/1/2000, then on 11th, 100*(1+0.015)=101.5; on 12th, 101.5*(1-0.007), so on..

I have tried:

#add a dummy column, calc accumulated values:

```
df['Accumulated Values']=100
acv=df['Accumulated Values']
acv[1:]=(df.rtns[1:]+1)*acv[1:].shift(1)
```

#add the column

```
df['Accumulated Values']=acv
```

The problem is `acv[1:].shift(1)` is always NaN for the first row.

Comment: Why not set the first row to 100? `df.iloc[0,1] = 100`

Comment: {df['Accumulated Values']=100} already cover that - setting first row to 100

Comment: No, but then you just operate on rtns...

Comment: sorry, missed this: 'acv=df['Accumulated Values']' before operate on acv